# Magento - remove "price.phtml" from the category list of products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to remove the prices from the category list of products. I search exactly to remove the link to the reference template file price.phtml;

In which xml layout files can I find it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a layout XML file can be that selective. Edit the file `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and remove all instances of this:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Alternatively you could hide it with CSS, but this wouldn't hide it from search engines if that's your intention:

```
.category-products .price-box { display: none; }
```